# Remove Admin Bar WordPress Code Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am having trouble with this code below -- can someone please help!

```
 // Remove the admin bar from the front end
 add_filer( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_fase' );
```

I really appreciate anyone even tkaing the time to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Is written as `fase` and `filer`

Reference check [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-wordpress-admin-bar-for-all-users-except-administrators/)

Comment: Correct answer, but [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar#Examples) is a better reference.